# Lilypond Swing Feeling

Tags: midi, lilypond, swing

How to properly write sheet music in swing-feeling with `lilypond`?

Just for clarification: in MuseScore, this can be achieved as explained 
[here](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/swing).

I'm a bit confused as I did not find anything useful in the internet.
I cannot simply write the hint as text annottaion since I'd like to convert the music to midi using `lilysong`, of course as swing.

The [`lilypond`-documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/what-goes-into-the-midi-output_003f) implicitly says that my goal is achievable:

> Unsupported in MIDI
>
> The following items of notation have no effect on the MIDI output, unless you use The Articulate script:
>
> - Rhythms entered as annotations, e.g. swing
> - [...]

I'm willing to use the *Articulate script*.
The documentation does, however, not mention how to enter this *swing rhythm annotation*.

Comment: I'm afraid that the Articulate script can't do it either. I had a short look at its code and the "inegalité" feature (which would be able to do this) is mentioned in the TODO section... The script should come along with base Lilypond, so you can see it for yourself (in my system, it's in `/usr/local/share/lilypond/2.19.62/ly/articulate.ly`; not sure about where to look for it on Windows).

Answer (score 2):

The documentation doesn't mention it because the comments in the script itself (in subdirectory `LilyPond\usr\share\lilypond\current\ly\articulate.ly` in my installation) say that swing, and several other playback features, are not implemented yet.

Actually, it's hard to implement swing "correctly" unless the basic rhythm of the music is very simple. If the notated rhythm divides the beats into parts that are smaller than half beats, applying a simple algorithm to adjust the rhythm usually gives the wrong result.

Comment: ok that sounds plausible. Do you know how, e.g., MuseScore achieves this functionality? At least for my purposes, I never have had troubles with swing so far.

Answer (score 2):

As of Lilypond 2.21.82 (probably in 2.20 too), there exists [a special swing script](http://partitura.org/wp-content/uploads/lilypond/html/Documentation/notation/enhancing-midi-output.html#the-swing-script). It provides a `\tripletfeel` command can be used in the following manner (for 8th notes, which is the most common way, hence the `8` as an argument):

```
\score {
  \tripletFeel 8 {
    % some music
  }
  \midi { }
}
```